# How can I un-capture some of shortcuts when I use VMPlayer?

Tags: vmware, shortcut

When I use VMPlayer, all keyboard message is captured to guest system.

I need some of shortcuts do not captured by guest system, for example, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

I use there shortcuts to manage my Windows Manager.